# I am implementing the authentication system on the front-end and login and logout work well, but I can't verify the token (AxiosError)

Tags: axios, middleware, bearer-token, verify, express-jwt

I tried confirming the middleware settings and the auth.service and auth.context, increased accepted headers, and temporarily expanded CORS allowed origins to all (*). Since the error isn't specific, I can't seem to move further.

My endpoint:

```
const { isAuthenticated } = require("../middleware/jwt.middleware.js");

router.get("/verify", isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`req.payload`, req.payload);
  res.status(200).json(req.payload);
});
```

My middleware:

```
const { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");
require("dotenv").config();

const isAuthenticated = jwt({
  secret: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
  algorithms: ["HS256"],
  requestProperty: "payload",
  credentialsRequired: false,
  getToken: getTokenFromHeaders,
});

function getTokenFromHeaders(req) {
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[0] === "Bearer"
  ) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    return token;
  }
  return null;
}

module.exports = {
  isAuthenticated,
};
```

on app.js:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5173");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH"
  );
  next();
});
app.use(isAuthenticated);
```

on my auth.service.js (to confirm I don't need any argument here)

```
class AuthService {
(...)
verify = () => {
    // return axios.post("http://localhost:5005/users/verify");
    return this.api.get("/users/verify");
  };
}
```

and finally on my auth.contextjs: (the error starts here on the .verify() because it heads straight to logging the error):

```
const storeToken = (token) => {
    localStorage.setItem("authToken", token);
  };

  const authenticateUser = () => {
    const storedToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
    if (storedToken) {
      authService
        .verify()
        .then((response) => {
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!
verify endpoint is a `POST` and not a `GET`